# General Solution of Non-Linear ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am a first year physics student with a question about the general solution of non-linear ODEs.

I recently looked through an argument in my lecture notes that for any n-th order **linear** ODE, a unique solution is specified by n-initial conditions and so it follows that the general solution will contain n coefficients in order to accommodate all possible solutions.

I have linked the "proof" below and while I understand the logic, I am wondering why the lecturer has specifically limits the case to linear ODEs. Where would this argument fail if applied to non-linear ODEs and do non-linear ODEs always have n undetermined constants in the general solution like their linear counterparts?

Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8MsH.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument would indeed break in general for non-linear ODE's because y as a function of y' might not be inyective and therefore invertible. However a similar result holds for a broader class of ODE's. While the solution to a non-linear ODE might not exist, if given certain conditions the solution is guaranteed to exist and be unique in a neighborhood around the inital condition. See [Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of the existence and uniqueness theorems, but I'm having trouble seeing how problems would occur for non-linear ODEs when differentiating. Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: Consider the equation $\sin(y') = y$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$. Then plugging in $t=0$ you have infinite values of $y'(0)$ that satisfy the equation. Namely $y'(0)=k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I believe I had the wrong idea about the "new things would come up" as opposed to that if the equation is not linear then y as a function of y' might not be inyective and therefore not invertible.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense